# Input length mismatch scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use a `DecisionTreeClassifier` to do some analysis but it is giving me the following error:

`ValueError: Number of features of the model must  match the input. Model n_features is 1 and  input n_features is 4`

I've used the same training and test sets for an `SVC` and a `GaussianNB` classifier and those both worked fine. Below is my code, I know the test and training set have the same design, that is, before being vectorized they take the form of a list containing strings. I don't know where the mismatch is coming from

```
#classify with just scikit

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from tools.striper import stripe, cleanupfiles
from tools.tweetprocessor import clean, wordclean

from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import tree

stripe(0.1)

training = []
traininglabel = []
test = []
testlabel = []

with open('tempdata/goodtraining.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = [wordclean(x) for x in clean(line.rstrip('\n')).split()]
        tweet = [x for x in tweet if len(x) >= 3]
        training.append(' '.join(tweet))
        traininglabel.append('good')
with open('tempdata/badtraining.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = [wordclean(x) for x in clean(line.rstrip('\n')).split()]
        tweet = [x for x in tweet if len(x) >= 3]
        training.append(' '.join(tweet))
        traininglabel.append('bad')
with open('tempdata/goodtest.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = [wordclean(x) for x in clean(line.rstrip('\n')).split()]
        test.append(' '.join(tweet))
        testlabel.append('good')
with open('tempdata/badtest.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = [wordclean(x) for x in clean(line.rstrip('\n')).split()]
        test.append(' '.join(tweet))
        testlabel.append('bad')

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0.1,max_df=0.9)
train_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(training)
test_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(test)

print (train_vect)
print (test_vect)

classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(train_vect.toarray(), traininglabel)
predictions = classifier.predict(test_vect.toarray())

print (classification_report(testlabel, predictions))

cleanupfiles()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
test_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(test)
```

to

```
test_vect = vectorizer.transform(test)
```

The `fit()` method of the vectorizer should only be called on the training data.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.